# Debug remote java application using Intellij

Tags: java, spring, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug remote java application in Intellij but unable to get sucess, The steps which I am doing is

**Run>Edit Configuration> Defaults> Remote**

[image]

What is/are I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a new Remote debugging configuration:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Take note of the port which IntelliJ plans to listen in Tomcat.  On my setup the port is `8000`, which is the default and this *should* be fine for your setup as well.  To change the Tomcat JPDA port, edit `catalina.bat` (or whatever your startup script is) and find a line which looks like the following:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
```

Second, make sure that you are building your project with `javac -g ...`.  The `-g` option means that debugging information will be turned on in your Spring WAR.

Finally, when you start Tomcat, use `catalina jpda start`, which will tell Tomcat to connect the debugger to port 8000.  When you want to connect to IntelliJ then use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and select your remote configuration from the menu.  Of course, you should add some breakpoints, without which it doesn't make much sense to be in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit the defaults. You need to use the [+] button to create a new Remote run configuration and specify its settings.